# concorde tsp build error to do with '-fPIC'

Tags: linux

I have previously built 'concorde tsp' on Linux with no problems. I think that Mint Linux 19.1 has changed something ant it now won't build, and suggests using the gcc "-fPIC" option. 
Has anyone succeeded in dealing with this issue ? I tried just adding
this as a gcc option in the Makefile, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution to this from the 'concorde' originator. It was to download the 'qsopt' variant which is built with the -fPIC option.